# transformClassesWithDexForDebug error importing javax.xml.stream

Tags: android, xml

I'm developing an app that need xml reading feature. Then I use javax.xml.stream library via importing jar file. I'm using Android studio.

The link where I downloaded jar file: [jar link](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjavaxxmlstreamjar.htm)

However, I got error on building the app.

> Error:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
>   Error:(org.apache.commons.digester.ExtendedBaseRules$1) that doesn't come with an
>   Error:associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
>   Error:compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
>   Error:solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
>   Error:and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
>   Error:this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
>   Error:indicate that it is *not* an inner class.

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

I've search through stackoverflow but no post work for me. Anyone can help me get out of this mess!!! Thank you!

**Update**

I cannot find out working solution for using javax.xml.stream. I ended up using [org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/xml.html) instead. Hope this helps someone else, and still hope someone can fix the error with xml stream library.

Answer (score 0):

Add those to you **`app`**`gradle.build` file:

```
android {
    // ...your other project settings...
    project.tasks.withType(com.android.build.gradle.tasks.Dex) {
        additionalParameters=['--core-library']
    }
}
dependencies {
    // ...deps settings...
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0' //enable multi-dex

}
```

Comment: Thank @Nir Duan for your reply. When I add above code to my app gradle build, I got error while gradle sync: "Could not get unknown property 'com' for object of type com.android.build.gradle.AppExtension." Can you please guide me to get over it